# CSV File Duplicate Archiver in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I've been given a CSV file which needs to be updated. In its current state, it stores the names and date uploaded of over 13,000 files, however many of the entries are duplicates. An entry is considered a duplicate if the first nine digits of the file's name are the same, however I want to keep the newest copy of each duplicate. I've been working on a Ruby program that will create a new CSV file that contains all of the file names of duplicates that need to be deleted, but I have little experience with Ruby (less than a week) and so I am struggling. The original CSV with all the files has been sorted by file name, so the duplicates are next to each other so I wrote this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'
updated_name = "FilesToDelete.csv"
previous = nil
filenames = CSV.read('All_filenames.csv')
duplicates = []
CSV.open(updated_name, "w") do |files|

    files << filenames.shift
    filenames.each do |row|

        next if row[0] == previous #This is where I don't know how to compare only first nine characters of the string
        previous = row[0]

        files << row


    end 

end
```

I really have no idea how to go about this task using Ruby so this code is probably very wrong. If you know a way of doing this, any help would be appreciated. I got this far using this thread: [ruby CSV duplicate row parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602334/ruby-csv-duplicate-row-parsing)

Comment: This csv file, does it contain one filename (and nothing more) per row?

Comment: I'd use a small SQLite database for this. That'd allow you to easily load the CSV, update it, remove duplicates and output the CSV with the most recent timestamps for the files.

Comment: @steenslag no there are 8 columns, including date created and etc. but the others are either all the same for each file or not necessary. I am only trying to include file name and date created in the new CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix my problem. The first thing I did was change the original CSV file so that the first column only had the first nine characters of each file name. I then sorted the CSV file by the first nine characters, and then by date created in reverse chronological order. This sort allowed me to use this code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'csv'
updated_name = "AllFilesForArchive.csv" # This should be changed based on which operation is used
previous = nil
filenames = CSV.read('All_filenames.csv')
duplicates = []
CSV.open(updated_name, "w") do |files|

    files << filenames.shift
    filenames.each do |row|
        # Next three lines are used to only list files to keep
        #next if duplicates.include?(row[0]))
        #duplicates.unshift row[0]
        #files << row

        # This if-else statement is used to only lists files to archive
        if row[0] == previous
            files << row
        else
            previous = row[0]
        end

    end
end
```

So this code allows me to create a new CSV containing the files to keep and a separate new CSV listing all the files to delete, based on which section of the `.each do` I put in comments.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the first 9 characters:

```
row[0,9] == previous[0,9]
```

Where `[0,9]` on a string is notation for "starting at offset zero, return nine characters", part of the [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method.

Note that you're not updating `previous`, so it will always be the same. Here's another approach:

```
filenames.each_with_index do |name, i|
  if (row == 0 || row[0,9] != filenames[i-1][0,9])
    files << row
  end
end
```

The `each_with_index` method is like `each` but includes an index value at the end which represents, in this case, the line number.

Comment: I tried to do what you said, but it caused an error (because of `name` which should be `row`, right?). Even when I switched it to `row`, the program just copied everything from the original. I managed to sort the original CSV by file and date uploaded as well since posting originally.